# SQL Server : getting "invalid column name"

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am working on writing a query but there are problems which I couldn't find. Here is my code

```
begin
    declare @v_max int
    declare @v_count int
    declare @sessionID int
    declare @sessionStart datetime
    declare @sessionEnd datetime

    declare my_cursor cursor local for
        select * from Test;

    open my_cursor
    fetch next from my_cursor INTO @sessionID, @sessionStart, @sessionEnd

    while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    begin
        select *  into **@v_count**
        from [dbo].[Test]
        WHERE **[dbo].[Test].[SessionStartTime]** > @sessionStart
        OR **[dbo].[Test].[SessionCloseTime]** < @sessionEnd

        if @v_count > @v_max 
            set @v_max = @v_count


        fetch next from my_cursor INTO @sessionID, @sessionStart, @sessionEnd
    end

    print @v_max;

    close my_cursor
    deallocate my_cursor
end
```

Bolded areas have problems:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 18
>   Invalid column name 'SessionStartTime'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
>   Invalid column name 'SessionCloseTime'.
>   Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
>   Incorrect syntax near '@v_count'.

Here is my Table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test]( 
    [ScenarioID] [bigint] NULL, 
    [SessionStartTime] [datetime] NOT NULL, 
    [SessionCloseTime] [datetime] NULL 
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

---

Here is my Table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test](
    [ScenarioID] [bigint] NULL,
    [SessionStartTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [SessionCloseTime] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Answer (score 5):

`@v_count` is declared as an `int` in the beginning of your query and not as a table. You can not use `SELECT * INTO @v_count` there.

Answer (score 3):

[`Select into`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa225219%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) creates a table.

You may want

```
select @v_count = count(*)
from [dbo].[Test] 
...
```

You also need to initalise @v_max at the start of your routine.

```
set @v_max = 0
```

As for your other problem, do you have columns called SessionStartTime and SessionCloseTime in your Test table?

Comment: As I commented earlier: SQL parser gives false errors near true errors sometimes. Try commenting out the SELECT * INTO @v_count line and check if it still gives you those invalid columns name errors.